# Rails 5 ActionView::Helpers capture method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in ruby on rails, and I want to practice it.
I'm stuck when I want to include a view into antoher view.
I want by doing that to have my posts into another view than of posts/index

`posts/index`

- method:

  ```
  def index
      @Posts = Post.all
  end
  ```
- view:

  ```
  <% @posts = capture do %>

     <% @posts.each do |post| %>
       <h3>
        <%= post.title %>
       </h3>
      <p>
       <%= post.content %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
  ```

`pages/index`

```
<h1> Index Of another pages </h1>
<%= @posts %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you need to save the reusable view code as a partial, and render it all places it's required.

To use a partial, save it down with an underscore prefix, i.e. `_posts.html.erb`.

This can then be rendered using:

```
<%= render 'path/to/posts' %>
```

You'll likely need to pass in the posts variable to the partial, as in the following:

```
<%= render 'path/to/posts', posts: @posts %>
```

And the change your view to use `posts` rather than `@posts`.

---

Update:

The result of `capture` is assigned to `@posts`, although this variable still wouldn't be available in another template - rather to be used again on the same page

Based on what you're saying about the project's structure, it sounds like you'd need the following:

in app/views/posts/_posts.html.web

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h3>
    <%= post.title %>
  </h3>
  <p>
    <%= post.content %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

In both controllers' `index` action:

`@posts = Post.all`

In the posts/index view:

`<%= render 'posts' %>`

In the pages/index view:

`<%= render 'posts/posts' %>`

I don't want to confuse things, but Rails has a little magic in there where -
 alternatively - you can define a partial `_post.html.erb` as follows:

```
<h3>
  <%= post.title %>
</h3>
<p>
  <%= post.content %>
</p>
```

And simply call `<%= render @posts %>` in each view. This would be the best 'Railsy' way of doing things.

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: It does not work, and I have an error


Missing partial posts/_posts with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:

Comment: And if i do that, I need to declare posts model into views ? If yes, I will go call n + 1 a database request no like "SELECT * FROM POSTS" ?

Comment: Where have you created the partial? You need to make sure you use the correct path to it. You should load the posts in the controller rendering the view - I'm a little unclear on the context you're using these partials in, but there shouldn't be any need for an N + 1 if you load / include the required posts correctly. Perhaps add a little more context of where these will be called into the question?

Comment: FYI here are the docs to using partial: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: I have 2 direcories, 1 directory for posts, and the other for static pages, and i'm not used the partial, but i used the [caputre](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) method of rails for include content pages into another pages

Comment: I could be wrong here, but it looks to me as if the result of `capture` is assigned to @posts, although this variable still wouldn't be available in another template - rather to be used again on the same page.

I'd really suggest working on getting the partial running - it's the established way of doing what you're trying to achieve. I'll update my answer to reflect the new info - hope it helps. Also, you'll only be hitting your db twice - there's no other model involved to create an N + 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force your index action to render another view, then go with follow code:

```
def index
  @Posts = Post.all
  render 'pages/index'
end
```

Correct me if I haven't get you

Comment: It doesn't work, and I want to include my posts into (n + 1) pages.